# How to display correctly a barcode using a QSvgWidget in PyQt5 with Python?

Tags: python, svg, pyqt5

I'm creating an app to generate barcodes using Python and PyQt5, I'm using the module **barcode-python** to generate an SVG file with the barcode, then I read the file and load it in a QSvgWidget, it shows the barcode but it doesn't look good, the thing is if I open the file in a browser It looks perfect.

[On the left you can see the barcode inside the QSvgWidget, on the right is the same barcode in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70ESx.png)

Somebody knows how to show in a correct way a SVG barcode created using the module **barcode-python**?

Comment: I think you shoud use right width and height  ratio to show SvgWidget, or use a picture to show it.

Comment: Hi @jie, thanks for taking the time to reply, but I found the solution, the problem is that when the python barcode module creates the SVG file with the barcode, it assigns millimeters as units for each strip, basically changing mm by px or leaving it empty solves the problem!